# Tags: negative-attention, backlash, and mistakes

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I just created [negative-attention](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative-attention) for the two Streisand-effect questions ([1](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1486/83), [2](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1487/83)).  I looked at our tags first and saw [mistakes](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistakes) and [backlash](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backlash).  Neither has a wiki, and the questions on each seemed related but not quite the same.

What changes, if any, should we make to these three tags?  It's possible that [negative-attention](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative-attention) should be a synonym of [backlash](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backlash), as the former nearly-inevitably leads to the latter.  Having a synonym rather than just retagging would produce a match if somebody starts to type "negative", which seems helpful.  But I don't know if that's true or valuable.

So, thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I agree that the two go together. Negative attention seems far broader than backlash to me and I'm not sure it is necessarily related.  Negative attention could be any kind of attention that shows a poor light, where as a backlash is a response to a particular stimuli.

Comment: That's a good point.  It's possible that some of our questions tagged "backlash" should be retagged "negative-attention"; I was definitely basing that on the sets of questions as much as the tag names.